# Remap vector of values between -1 to 1

Tags: math

I have two sampled vectors, there one vector maximum value is **0.8** and the minimum value is **-0.8**. 2nd vector minimum value is 0.2 and maximum value is 0.3. There 1st and 2nd vector,  I want to re map all the values in sampled vector between **-1 to 1**. How do I do that. Im looking for method which applying outlined two vectors. Thank you in advance.

Sampled vector 1.

```
[ -0.8, 0.7 , -0.23, 0.56, 0.456, -0.344, -0.75, 0.8]
```

Sampled vector 2.

```
  [ 0.2, 0.23,  0.21,  0.29, 0.26, 0.25, 0.3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General formula to map `xmin..xmax` range onto `new_min..new_max` one:

```
X' = new_min + (new_max - new_min)*(X - xmin)/(xmax-xmin)

  for destination range -1..1:
X' = -1 + 2 * (X - xmin) / (xmax-xmin)

  for source range 0.2..0.3:
X' = -1 + 20 * (X - 0.2) = -5 + 20 * X
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to normalize between [-1, 1]

Obtain the ratio:

`norm_ratio = 1/.8`

and multiply every element in your vector to get the desired result

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I updated my questions. Please refer the updated question. I really appreciate your answer. It would be really helpful if i can apply your method to my 2nd sampled vector too. But seems normRatio of that one 1/0.3 , when i want to get lower boundary it fails.